# How do I set text within pie chart slices done with QPainter?

Tags: c++, qt

I am just starting out qt and have attempted to make a pie chart and I have the following code

```
QPainter painter(this);
QPen pen;
QRectF size;
pen.setColor(Qt::white);
pen.setWidth(0);
painter.setPen(pen);
if(this->height()>this->width()){
    size = QRectF(5,5,this->width()-10, this->width()-10);
}
else{
    size = QRectF(5,5,this->height()-10, this->height()-10);
}
double sum = 0.0, startAngle = 0.0;
double angle = 0.0, endAngle, percent;

for(auto i = 0; i < qvValues.size(); i++){
    sum += qvValues[i];
}
for(auto i = 0; i < qvValues.size(); i++){
    percent = qvValues[i] / sum;
    angle = percent *360.0;
    endAngle = startAngle + angle;
    painter.setBrush(qvColors[i]);
    painter.drawPie(size, startAngle*16, angle*16);
    painter.drawText(size,"text");
    startAngle = endAngle;
}
```

And am getting the following result

pie chart

[image]

My question is, how would one be able to use the drawText() method in the QPainter class to add text within each of the pie slices? Specifically would I need to get the coordinates of the slices pass them into drawText()? If so how would you access its x and y?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385190/i-expect-to-have-percent-inside-each-part-of-the-piechart

Comment: Are you the same user or do you know each other? The code they use is the same, and they want the same.

Comment: This is a clear dupe. Shame.